# How to check if the biometric authentication dialog is displayed?

Tags: java, android, android-biometric, biometricmanager

In my application i use `BiometricManager` for creating system verification dialog:

```
                mBiometricManager = new ch.instaguard2.insta.app.utils.biometric.BiometricManager.BiometricBuilder(BaseActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(L.Companion.get(R.string.enhance_security))
                    .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setDescription(L.Companion.get(R.string.biometric_description))
                    .setNegativeButtonText(L.Companion.get(R.string.use_pin_code))
                    .build();
                //start authentication
                mBiometricManager.authenticate(this);
```

But it has only `dismisDialog()` method for control this dialog. How i can check is dialog showing now (like default `dialog.isShown()`)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but something like this could be approached:

```
private boolean isBiometricDialogShowing = false;
mBiometricManager = new ch.instaguard2.insta.app.utils.biometric.BiometricManager.BiometricBuilder(BaseActivity.this)
    .setTitle(L.Companion.get(R.string.enhance_security))
    .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setDescription(L.Companion.get(R.string.biometric_description))
    .setNegativeButtonText(L.Companion.get(R.string.use_pin_code))
    .build();
mBiometricManager.authenticate(new BiometricCallback() {
   @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        // Handle authentication failure
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationCancelled() {
        // Handle authentication cancellation
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccessful() {
        // Handle authentication success
    }

if (isBiometricDialogShowing) {
    // The biometric authentication dialog is currently displayed
} else {
    // The biometric authentication dialog is not displayed
}
}
```

Changing the isBiometricDialogShowing value can control whether the biometric authentication dialog is displayed or not.